# Mouse Position control when wrapX is true

Tags: openlayers-3

I've noticed that the values displayed by ol.control.MousePosition are not wrapped like the tiles are when wrapX equals true. This can be seen in this example: http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/mouse-position.html

Is there a way to change the output so it also shows the coordinates values wrapped?

Comment: Maybe you report this (unexpected?) behavior directly to [core developers](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/issues)?

Comment: you may change the `CoordinateFormatType`. here is the api doc-->http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.html#.CoordinateFormatType. Asign a function that accepts an ol.Coordinate and return the display string.